# HTTPError at /social-auth/login/twitter/ 403

Tags: django, ssl, twitter, oauth

I am trying to login twitter with oauth. I have included ssl certificate with lets encrypt secure my url,Thus my url is https but still i'm getting this error where should i change in my django code.

I have used social-oauth library for twitter login

Answer (score 0):

`social-auth` needs `https` it wont work on http

instead of going `192.x.x.x.x:xxxx` or `127.x.x.x.x:xxxx` use `localhost` it will work only then, because they need https facebook twitter and etc...

just in the adressbar go 
`localhost:8000` and it will work had the same issue with facebook

Comment: we already have a domain with https certificate installed https://humbusy.tk/social-auth/login/twitter/

Comment: verify your keys it should work did you try with new keys? did you try with facebook too?

Comment: Request URL: http://humbusy.tk/social-auth/login/twitter/  this is the request url , i believe since it does not have https , problem is being generated . (I clicked on twiiter sign in and above error generated.)

Comment: Did you include social-auth in your urls.py try making a Facebook button and see if it works with fb... Did you test it before deploying..., show me your `installed-apps`, `urls.py`,  and the button html please so we can figure out where the error comes from